# Misterious dialog pops up after to scan a qr code with zxing library

Tags: android, zxing

I'm buildind a simple android aplication for to scan QR codes using zxing as        external library. Everything works fine until I to scan a QR code that contains a link. After that pops up the follow message: Open link to the clipboard?
And this message remains on the screen even after I close the application and I have to restart my phone to the message disappear.
I have no idea why this is happening. Below is an print screen and my codes.
I don't know if this is related, but the target api in my project is api level 23 and the api level of my device is api level 21.

[misterious dialog bellow screen after to scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYJKV.jpg)

[and remains after closing the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsJCr.jpg)

build.gradle [app module]

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.atriuz.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    // Zxing libraries
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:2.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-integration:2.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.atriuz.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code section that call zxing capture activity to scan QR code. [Is in onCreate of MainAtivity]

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            mostrarMensagem();//some error message
        }

    }
});
```

And onActivityResult method

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        final String qrcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
        text.setText(qrcode);
    }
}
```

I thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I had rewrite the qr code read method.

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            readQR(view);
        }
    });

    public void readQR(View view) {
        IntentIntegrator intent = new IntentIntegrator(this);

        intent.addExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Put qr code inside marked area");
        intent.addExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", 1000);
        intent.addExtra("SCAN_HEIGHT", 550);

        try {

            intent.initiateScan();
            //startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            showMessage();
        }
    }

    private void showMessage() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Do you want to install barcode scanner?")
            .setMessage("YouTo read a qr code you need to install zxin barcode scanner.")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setPositiveButton("Install",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(ZXING_MARKET));
                            try {
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { // If don't have play store
                                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(ZXING_DIRECT));
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancell", null).show();

    }
```